# Difference in behavior of directly invoking a shell script and exec it?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file path to a script in a shell variable that if run it directly, it runs fine (the path has a whitespace escaped with a `\` there is a white space after the `\`), but when I try via

```
exec $script "$@"
```

the whitespace becomes in the script path becomes an issues and breaks the path to the script. How can I fix this? (I can't change the given path that has a whitespace in it)

Comment: Try: `exec "$script" "$@"`

Comment: thanks but `script="is/already\ a/string"`, shouldn't that cover it?

Comment: Can you please add a complete, reproducible example? Including the definition of `$script` ?

Comment: Backslashes aren't processed when expanding a variable. The only processing that's done is word splitting and globbing.

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes *before* expanding variables; as a result, putting escapes in a variable's value doesn't do what you expect because by the time they're part of the command, it's too late for it to have the intended effect.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put backslashes into the variable. Quote its expansion.

```
script="is/already a/string"
exec "$script" "$@"
```